# How change texts in the Login and register pages

Tags: magento2, phtml

I am using Magento 2 and the Mr Bara template, I have managed to change the home and product view, but I can not find where to change the login and registration texts, I want to add an image as well and that should be done in the template . Has anyone managed to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check if the below files are already present in your theme:

> /vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/login.phtml

and

> /vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml

Your template location will be like below:

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Customer/templates/form/login.phtml

and

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml

If these files are not present then copy those from vendor location to your theme location as above and do the customisation.

Flush the cache and check if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Magento Login page and Register Page are displaying by below files

> magento/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/login.phtml
>
> magento/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml

But you shouldn't directly change in these files. For this, you've to override these template files in your theme

For login template copy login.phtml file to below path

> magento/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Customer/templates/form/login.phtml

For register template copy register.phtml file to below path

> magento/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml

Answer (score 0):

Please check these two phtml files

vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/login.phtml
vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml

Answer (score 0):

Hello @EvinceDevelopment,

Can Anyone help me step by step to do this? I am looking for the same thing but Not sure what others files and folders are required to do this.

Thank you,